# Дублируются куки с сервера и клиента

Tags: php, javascript, cookie

При создании куки с сервера и клиента, они, если посмотреть в отладчике, сохраняются для разных доменов. Разница в них лишь в точке перед именем, например `site.ru` и `.site.ru`.

Соответственно работа с ними осложняется, так как по имени их изменить корректно не получается. Если точнее, не получается это сделать с созданными куки на сервере. Сервер при наличии куки созданной через javascript меняет её корректно, но если сначала создать на сервере, то домен пишется с точной, и javascript создает куки заново с тем же именем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**PHP:**

```
setcookie("ustp", $ustp, time()+(3600*200),'/',$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$.cookie('ustp', ustp, { expires: 5, path: '/'});
```

Как решить эту проблему? Как "синхронизировать" создание и изменение куки?

Comment: Добавь еще дополнительное значение которое определяет домен с которого доступен cookie, и выставь там и там одинаковые значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за подсказку [Ruslan Melnichenko](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/257542/ruslan-melnichenko). Для моей задачи решение оказалось следующим:

```
$.cookie('ustp', ustp, { expires:5, path:'/', domain:window.location.href.split('/')[2]});
```

Comment: Есть же location.hostname